# Problems getting OSVR to initialise the HMD Display with Oculus DK2

Tags: virtual-reality, oculus, osvr

I am using a Oculus DK2 (v0.8) and OSVR SDK. I'm having a problem getting the HMD to run/display anything.
The Oculus samples and the OSVR samples do work however, so the osvr_server seems to run fine.
My application itself renders a test scene just fine when not using a HMD.

I tried two approaches:

First, just creating a osvr context and creating a DisplayConfig object. This seems to work, but DisplayConfig::checkStartup() fails (I do this in a loop, calling update on the context when the checkStartup call is failing). I used the OpenGLSample.cpp as a guide for this

Second, I tried using a RenderManager, but the call to createRenderManager results in a crash within the RenderManager.dll. I get the same crash wether I create the graphics lib object myself or if I let the library create it.

I am quite stuck now, since the demos and examples do work, I have no idea where to look for the error on my side. Creating the context works, querying interfaces as well, but the crash with createRenderManager is beyond me.

Does anyone have any hints or ideas what the problem could possibly be?

Regards and thanks in advance

pettersson

Answer (score 0):

RenderManager should not crash during open.  There have been a couple of bug fixes recently to avoid that happening, and the latest RenderManager binaries, libraries and header files are available with the SDK download from http://osvr.github.io/using/ along with updated copies of the example programs.

When something goes wrong in RenderManager, it usually reports that to standard error.  We're moving that to a logging interface, but for now it should show up on the console.  Posting an output of that as an issue at https://github.com/sensics/OSVR-RenderManager/issues is a good way to let the developers know that there is a problem.  Of course, providing the same sort of information you provided here will be helpful as well.